# Is there a logic behind the naming of the Rebel Alliance's starfighters?

Tags: star-wars

Looking at the most recognizable ones at least, I was wondering why the older starfighters of the Rebel Alliance are called X-Wing, Y-Wing, and the newer ones A-Wing and B-Wing.
A logical order would be to name the first model A-Wing and so on.

**Is there any system or structure supporting the ship naming scheme**, or is this just coincidence/will of Mr. Lucas ?
Or is it because you could say the ship's shape corresponds somewhat to those letters (even the B-Wing does, albeit remotely). AFAIK, these four examples do not share one manufacturer, which adds another dimension to the question.

*BTW,
[this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21840/why-does-an-x-wing-have-this-name-when-there-is-no-x-in-the-aurebesh-alphabet) is interestingly related.*

Comment: I always thought it was because of the correspondence between ship and letter shape, though I don't see the (remote) correspondence you do for the B-Wing.

Comment: The names are based on the shape, but I don't have a reference for that right now.

Comment: @numaroth I took the blueprint image, rotated it and flipped it. [The shape is a little bit of a stretch, but it's there](http://imgur.com/TFW0GCb)

Comment: I read somewhere that the B-wing was named the bladewing in early concept art, and later renamed to B-wing to match the others (X, Y and A). Can't find a source to back that up right now though.

Comment: It's about the shapes with the Rebel Alliance.  However it is different with the Empire.  The TIE Fighters are "Twin Ion Engine".

Comment: Funny that the names reference an alphabet that doesn't exist to these characters. George Lucas is a useless idiot.

Comment: As they said on rifftrax - "Prepare to lock x-foils in 'sell toys' position"

Comment: @user973810 Yeah, he even had the pilots talking in a language _they wouldn't even know!_ What a jerk, that Lucas guy!

Comment: @Richard: Only that they are summarily called "*S*-foils" in the movie (and various supplementary material). ;-)

Comment: It is explicitly stated that X-Wing Fighters look like Xs in "Star Wars: Adventures in ABC".  (http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Adventures_in_ABC). I assume that's canon.

Comment: Ackbar’s association to the B-Wing was introduced by WEG in their Strike Force: Shantipole adventure module in 1988. The B-Wing had already been a B-Wing for some 5 years before this fictional EU association was created in-universe to provide the now Legends’ B-Wing origin.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The names are because the shapes of the craft resemble that letter.

When viewed from the front or back, and [X-wing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/X-wing_starfighter) looks like the letter X :

[image: X-wing]

When viewed from above/below, a [Y-wing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/BTL_Y-wing_starfighter) looks like the letter Y :

[image: Y-wing]

When viewed from above/below, and [A-wing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/RZ-1_A-wing_interceptor) looks like the letter A :

[image: A-wing]

When viewed from the side, a [B-wing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/A/SF-01_B-wing_starfighter) looks like a lowercase letter b :

[image: B-Wing]

The B-Wing comparison is a little more tenuous. Here's how it looks with the letter overlayed:

[image: B-wing with letter]

Comment: I still don't see the "b" from the B-wing but good pictures. Also, your B-wing link points to the A-wing article.

Comment: @Null thanks, I've corrected the link now.

 The B-wing is definitely the most tenuous comparison.

Comment: I always thought "T-wing" would be a better name given that it is shaped like a "t".

Comment: The `B` is formed with the wings going from the "normal" position to the fighting position, like they are on the images. They are vertically aligned with the rest of the bomber when in "normal" position.

Comment: You may want to mention the E-wing fighter as well, which basically resembled the Z-95 Headhunter in shape - or an X-Wing with the foils closed. From above, it looked like a capital E.

Comment: @Null It could be argued that it resembles a "B" just like constellations resemble their shapes/animals. They don't *really* resemble them, but with some imagination you can easily make that shape from those vertices.

Comment: @Null there was a T-wing Interceptor.  It was designed to replace the A-wing.  I don't know if linking to [this wiki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/T-wing_interceptor) is acceptable here but there's some info.

Comment: The engineer from Wings of the Masters (Rebels S2) refers to the prototype B-wing as the "Blade wing," which may indicate a different source for the name than hull shape.

Comment: It's handy that, in the galaxy far far away, they use the same alphabet as us.

Comment: Based on the new Disney canon, the backstory of the B-Wing was revealed in Star Wars Rebels, and the designer called it the "Blade Wing" and it was shortened to B-Wing.

Comment: I always thought that the B in B-Wing referred to "Bomber", since B-Wings are heavy assault bombers.  This is corroborated by the fact that star wars space fights are based on WWI dogfights, and B-Wings play the role that bombers played there.  I guess it always reminded me of real-life bombers, like B-2 etc.

Answer (score 13):

B-Wing is short for "Blade Wing", named so for its long sleek blade-like profile. Classed as a Blockade Buster because its maneuverability was terrible for dog fights. Enough firepower to ruin anything and thin enough nothing can hit it.

This is revealed the Star Wars Rebels episode "Wings of the Master".  In that episode, the [B-Wing prototype was revealed and referred to as the Blade Wing](http://www.starwars.com/databank/b-wing-prototype-blade-wing).

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Please provide a citation for your claim that it is short for "Blade Wing".

Comment: @Null I don't want to edit it for the OP but it was part of the new Disney canon (Star Wars Rebels).  But here's the citation: http://www.starwars.com/databank/b-wing-prototype-blade-wing

Comment: @psubsee2003 Good find! The source shouldn't be left in a comment, though. You can either post your own answer with the source, or edit the citation into this answer.

Comment: @Null I was reluctant to add so much to the OP's answer, but I've proposed the edit.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Edit approved. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

The X-Wing is clearly named after the shape the "wings" have in attack position: an X.

The Y-Wing does form a Y, when looking from above; though clearly less recognizable than the X-Wing.

For the newer ones, though, whoever did the naming lost me.

The A-Wing can be said to ROUGHLY resemble a capital A when seen from above, but the B-Wing really just seems to have needed a name...

If anyone can explain the B-Wing, please do, though.

Oh, see the [neat answer with the pictures](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/68671)! But I still have a VERY hard time seeing a "b" on the B-wing!

Answer (score 5):

This odd naming convention was addressed by Pablo Hidalgo in [Star Wars Insider #60](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_60) from 2002.

> **Q. Why are B-wings called B-wings? They look nothing like a "b"! Shouldn't they be called T-Wings?**
>
> **PH:** If you tilt your head the right way and squint, you could argue that they kind of look like a lower-case "B". Not buying it? Well, one theory is that the "b" actually stands for "blade", since the profile of a B-Wing fighter has a passing resemblance to an inverted knife, with the cockpit being the rounded pommel of the handle and the lower foils being the blade
>
> [image]
>
> A convenient in-universe answer is that then-commander Ackbar and Verpine shipbuilders specifically designed the B-wing as an answer to the Imperial threat of Nebulon-B escort frigates.
>
> The real-world answer can be found at ILM. When model-makers were assigned to the two new Rebel fighters for Return of the Jedi, the were labeled "A" and "B" fighters. The "A" ended up being the A-wing, and the "B" the B-wing, regardless of what they actually looked like. During production, the B-wing also earned the nickname the "Bill-wing" after model-maker Bill George.
>
> Incidentally, LucasArts developed a T-wing starfighter as cannon fodder in their TIE Fighter flight-sim game, so that letter is already taken.

Answer (score 4):

The B-Wing isn't named after it's appearance. Can't quote sources, but the B-Wing was the personal design of Admiral Ackbar as a new class of lighter, faster bombers to replace the heavy and slow Y-Wing. 'B' stands for 'Bomber', not it's shape.

The other three are indeed named after their appearance.

Comment: "The name B-wing came from the craft's remote similarity in appearance to the lowercase letter b" - http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/A/SF-01_B-wing_starfighter

Comment: @Moogle I'll have to find the source but the B is the lines formed when the wings go from normal to fighting position.

Comment: Just posting what I remember from the books. I've read bunches, but it's been years. This was a specific fact that really stood out to me from wherever I read it, and I would still trust that memory over a fansite statement of 'remote similarity in appearance' which to me is obviously wrong. You don't have to trust that memory, though. I'm just giving my two cents. 

If it was 'i' wing or 't' wing then sure, I'd see it. 'B' or 'b' doesn't make sense.

Comment: I've saw that on a technical sheet of the B-wing (from the first edition of Star wars D&D like rpg or pc star wars game, one of those) quite a few years back (10+). I still have the books for the RPG, so I'll look into them. It was so clearly apparent why it was called B-wing from that tech sheet I never needed to wonder why again.

Comment: That's the closest I could find on the [internet](http://images.wikia.com/starwars/images/f/f2/Bwing_egvv.jpg). It doesn't show up like a B but the lines on the tech sheet started under the rotation axe of the wings to the outside, making the B clear.

Comment: There are those that say the "B" stands for "Blade" and refer to it as the "Blade-wing".

Answer (score 1):

None of the above.

When they were making the movies they did not name the ships. They were all called starfighters. But when it was time to introduce two new fighters, in order to identify the models, they were assigned letters: A and B.

Coincidentally the A fighter actually looks somewhat like a capital A, but the B had no resembling to the letter. They kept the name anyway in the toys release, and later tried to give some explanation like "it's short for blade" or "it looks like a lower case b when it's upside down and you are looking at it with one eye closed".

Truth is it was a cool looking ship which could do cool moves rotating the cockpit, which did not get enough screen time because it wasn't easy to spot on screen with the black sky in the background (some scenes involving b wings were in fact cut in post production).

Also, there is no in-universe explanation to these names, as they use a different alphabet, and X, Y, A, B (and E) do not look like latin letters.

[image]

Comment: I was pretty sure that in the first movie they talked about "X-wings" and "Y-wings" and not _just_ generally "fighters."  But your comment about the alphabet not matching is very interesting. :)

Comment: The alphabet doesn’t necessarily have to match. “X” isn’t just a letter; it’s also an English word meaning “the shape of two crossed diagonal lines.” Presumably Galactic Basic has its own word for the same shape, and the most elegant translation into English is “X.”

Comment: I'm guessing they don't speak English at all, tbh.