# How does the B-Wing's cockpit maintain 'correct' orientation in space?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, return-of-the-jedi

One of the most iconic ships in all of Star Wars, the B-Wing resembles more of a *t* than a *b*. Other than that, its cockpit is located at one end of the ship and can be seen to being able to change orientations.

**Q**: Is there any *source* describing how the cockpit changes its orientation and how it decides what the correct orientation is?

Comment: Wookiepedia says it's gyro-stabilised...which seems logical

Comment: The Return of the Jedi Sketchbook showed that it could rotate, but it did not address how that was controlled.

Comment: With a weight. Since it was made in the early 80s, now I'm left wondering if it was made out of lead...

Comment: I thought I saw somewhere that the B stood for blade, so I went looking and found an answer to this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68670/is-there-a-logic-behind-the-naming-of-the-rebel-alliances-starfighters/68677#68677) which contains a link referencing Rebels that [supports this](http://www.starwars.com/databank/b-wing-prototype-blade-wing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the Star Wars Databank article on the B-Wing, the *pilot* decides whether to lock the gyro to a local horizon or, presumably, to let the cockpit align itself with the orientation of the ship itself.

> *The B-wing's command pod has a unique gyroscopic control system. **The
> pilot can orient it so that it always stays level with a horizon line.**
> No matter which way the B-wing may maneuver laterally, its pilot
> remains upright.*
>
> <sub><sup>[B-WING FIGHTER - StarWars.com](http://www.starwars.com/databank/b-wing-fighter)</sup></sub>

---

This is discussed at some length in the (Legends) video game [Star Wars: Rogue Squadron II: Rogue Leader](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rogue_Squadron_II:_Rogue_Leader)

> *Because the cockpit is surrounded by a unique gyro-stabilization
> system, **the pilot always remains stationary, even as the rest of the
> ship rotates during flight.***

And in this image from [Star Wars: Card Trader](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Card_Trader). Note that the image was originally taken from a set of Legends blueprints found in the [Essential Guide to Vehicles](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Essential_Guide_to_Vehicles_and_Vessels) factbook.

[image]

And you can see how it would work in practice.

Comment: That toy is sick

Comment: @Petersaber - I had one of those, along with this [bad boy](http://www.starwars.com/news/the-vintage-vault-revisiting-kenners-millennium-falcon). A few years ago I tried to locate them in the attic only to find out that my mother had sold them at a yard sale for a fiver each.

Comment: Appereantly every (at that time) kid geek had a mom who sold/gave away his toys/collectibles without his knowledge for nothing...  I feel your pain.

Comment: @Petersaber - In fairness she also sold a metric ton of other plastic crap from China that I had up there. How was she to know that that particular piece would be worth thousands just a few years later?

Comment: Monetary value was not my point - shotgun approach to throwing stuff away was