# Do falcons, the birds, exist in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, millennium-falcon, xkcd

Inspired by this comic from XKCD:
[image: XKCD Etymology comic]

Is there anything to confirm whether or not falcons exist in the Star Wars Universe? If they don't then what is the in-universe reason for the name of the Millennium Falcon?

Comment: Why did this get a DV?

Comment: Not sure we need a Millennium Falcon tag, though...

Comment: does anyone in the movies ever use the word 'millenium' to mean 1000 years?

Comment: @MikeEdenfield I assumed that millenium was just the translation from Galactic Basic to English for the concept of 1000 years (whatever they call it).

Comment: @Null I wouldn't have created one, but as it already exists I thought I'd use it.

Comment: @Moogle in which case, I would also assume "Falcon" is just a translation from Galactic Basic, to English, of some random bird-type thing. No proof, though :)

Comment: Do they have the letter "X" in their alphabet to call it an X-Wing?

Comment: @Geoff [Why does an X-Wing have this name when there is no “X” in the Aurebesh alphabet?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/21840/5184)

Comment: You should link to the original comic in the question.

Comment: Yes, [bloody hundreds](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Birds)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Legends:**

> The bat-falcon was a swift species of flying creatures. It inspired
>   the name of the starship Millennium Falcon.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bat-falcon

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Millennium_Falcon_(novel)

> The snow falcon was an avian native to Rhinnal.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Snow_falcon

> The spire falcon was a bird native to the planet Coruscant. It was at
>   the top of the food chain of animals such as gully rats, grate toads,
>   ferro-worms, and trantor pigeons.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Spire_falcon

Regarding canon - other than the Falcon name it appears not. It seems an unnecessary question imo - one could engage in ever increasing navel gazing over the necessity of language use in the film. Do ducks exist in canon? They are referenced in Episode 1. Does a Star Wars duck look like a duck and walk like a duck or is it different from an earth duck?

The name itself inherently implies that such a creature exists in some form and that is swift and agile. This is the simplest and logical explanation

Comment: Disney have really made these things difficult. I'll leave this open for a bit to see if there's a canon answer, otherwise I'll accept this. Either way have an upvote.

Comment: @Moogle - truth!

Comment: @Moogle If you are willing to accept a Legends answer, please use the Star Wars Legends tag so answerers will know whether Legends is acceptable or not.

Comment: @Null - thanks for the clarification as well - I've never paid any attention other than to try and differentiate in the answer itself. I do think there is value in addressing what has come before (as long as it is identified as such) because Disney doesn't preclude mining from Legends material

Comment: "Trantor pigeons"?  That's an amusing shout-out to the probable inspiration for Coruscant...